# Grep special character #‘

Tags: linux, grep

trying to grep `"#‘om"` but not able to escape or account for the quote char. I tried `grep -F`, `grep -e`, `grep -n` or simply `grep "#\‘om"` to no avail.

Comment: `echo '#‘om' | grep '#‘om'` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That quote is not the simple quote character it appears to be.  It's not clear whether copying-and-pasting the quote character from this website is accurate.

```
$ echo '‘' | cat -v
M-bM-^@M-^X

$ echo '‘' | xxd
$ 00000000: e280 980a                                ....
```

So, it appears the problem is one of character sets.

Note, however, that the following works for me:

```
$ echo '‘' | grep -F '‘'
‘
```

As does the following:

```
$ echo '#‘om' | grep -F '#‘om'
#‘om
```

It would help to see exactly what is being tried.  Perhaps use `xxd` to confirm what bytes are making up that quote.

Comment: ash, I confirm the bytes being `00000000: e280 980a` and not sure what happened but I can now do `grep -r "#\‘om"` without fail. ready to chew my hat..thanks for the xxd command, I learnt something new.

Comment: ODT format may be a binary format, in which case grep won't work.  Grep only works on text files and is line-oriented (either an entire line matches and is displayed, or it does not match and is suppressed).